# How to update a TextView from within onPostExecute

Tags: android, android-asynctask, textview

Need help here, about onPostExecute.  If I want to put the update on textView what should be the code and what should I do?.

```
@Override
protected Value[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
    Variable batteryLevel = apiClient.getVariable(VARIABLE_ID);
    Value[] variableValues = batteryLevel.getValues();

    return variableValues;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {
    // Update your views here
}
```

Comment: `onPostExecute` is run from the main/UI thread, so you're allowed to update your UI elements as you normally do.

Comment: either pass the view(s) reference in the asyncTask constructor, and access them from onpostExecute() or make the view(s) reference global so onPostexecute() can access them

Comment: Thanks Guys. If i want to get the data from the cloud and i want to update it on the textView. what should i do? ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows, save reference to TextView as member and use it in nested AsyncTask:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewID);
    ...
    }

    private YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask{
    ...
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {
            if(textView != null)
                textView.setText("your text");

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vitaliy A. but what if?, i want to get data from the cloud get you teach me how?

Comment: Requesting data should be done on doInBackground().For http requests you can use very simple lib called OkHttp: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

Comment: can i use that lib in android studio, i have already have a lib https://github.com/ubidots/ubidots-java. and i have here the code of sending data http://ubidots.com/docs/devices/android.html. how can update the views?

Answer (score 0):

If you want get last value from Ubidots to your textview. You can try this, but u must set the textview first OnCreate

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {
            // Update your views here

            String status = Double.toString(variableValues[0].getValue());
//this is textview for show last value from ubidots
            mBatteryStatus.setText(status);

        }
    }
```