# Asynctask for update button

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

How to update my UI button for disabled button on/off if i have condition. The condition : if i get value = 1.0 the button power on is disabled & and if i get value 0 the button power off disabled. I want the button always show up the new value.

This is my code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_controller, container, false);
        mSwitchStatus  = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.statusSwitch);
        ImageButton On = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.on);
        ImageButton Off = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.off);


        callAsynchronousTask();

            On.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), "ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SendApi sendApi = new SendApi();
                    sendApi.execute();
                }
            });

            Off.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplication(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    SendApi sendApi = new SendApi();
                    sendApi.execute();
                }
            });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }
```

Repeat AsyncTask

```
public void callAsynchronousTask() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            GetApi getApi = new GetApi();
                            getApi.execute();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            android.util.Log.i("Error", "Error");
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 100);
    }
```

AsyncTask for GETApi

```
public class GetApi extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Value[]> {
        private final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private final String SWITCHID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; 
        private ImageButton On,Off ;

        @Override
        protected Value[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
            Variable statusSwitch = apiClient.getVariable(SWITCHID);
            Value[] variableValues = statusSwitch.getValues();

            return variableValues;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {

            String status = Double.toString(variableValues[0].getValue());
            mSwitchStatus.setText(status);

            if(status.equals("1.0")){
                On.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }
```

Fragment_controller.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#1d4851"
    tools:context=".activity.ControllerFragment">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/off"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_off"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="79dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/on"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/on"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/on"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_on"
        android:layout_marginTop="87dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/off"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Water Pump Controller "
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="  "
        android:id="@+id/statusSwitch"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what error you are getting in this code ?

Comment: nothing, but the button not updated, 
if i change status.getText().toString().equals("1.0"); my apps crash
@AnwarKamal

Comment: make it status.getText().toString().equals("1");

Comment: or show me the crash report

Comment: hi @AnwarKamal i can't make status.getText() because status is string 
this is crash report when i debug
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.medyanto.iotsmartplant, PID: 8159 java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at com.example.medyanto.iotsmartplant.activity.ControllerFragment$GetApi.onPostExecute(ControllerFragment.java:222)
at com.example.medyanto.iotsmartplant.activity.ControllerFragment$GetApi.onPostExecute(ControllerFragment.java:198)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
in this android screen : unfortunately, apps has stopped

Comment: if i change to be like this 
if(mSwitchStatus.getText().toString().equals("1"))
            {
                On.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
the button not update

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the stacktrace plus that code. Comments are are not meant for that

Comment: `mSwitchStatus` or `On` is null according to your error. Please check that `fragment_controller.xml` contains all those views you are trying to find

Comment: in fragment_controller i set text="  " @cricket_007

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. What part of the NullPointerException do you not understand? Are you sure that `variableValues[0]` isn't null?

Comment: you have initialize it in onCreateView like ImageButton On = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.on); , How you are getting it in onPostExecute?It is un initialzed

Comment: And to disable you have to call setEnable(false)

Comment: @cricket_007 On is null and variableValues[0] not null

Comment: Your edits make it look like your error is now at `On.setClickListener`. Why did you remove the line that assigns that variable?

Comment: I trying for initialize imagebutton to main activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have `initialize` your button in `onCreateView` like

```
ImageButton On = (ImageButton)rootView.findViewById(R.id.on);
```

and trying to access it in onPostExecute().they aren't global.

And to disable you have to call `setEnable(false)` not `setVisibility`

And you can also send it as **Rathna Kumaran** said.

```
public class GetApi extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Value[]> {
        private Button button;
        public GetApi(Button mButton){
            this.button = button;
        }
        private final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        private final String SWITCHID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        @Override
        protected Value[] doInBackground(Object... params) {
            ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(API_KEY);
            Variable statusSwitch = apiClient.getVariable(SWITCHID);
            Value[] variableValues = statusSwitch.getValues();

            return variableValues;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Value[] variableValues) {

            String status = Double.toString(variableValues[0].getValue());
            mSwitchStatus.setText(status);

            if(status.equals("1.0")){
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have initialize Image button in main class

Comment: where you have initiaize in Activity or fragment.

Comment: in activity class

Comment: sample for @Rathna Kumaran answer is also added.

Comment: I believe the AsyncTask is an inner class. Otherwise, obviously the code wouldn't compile

Answer (score 0):

1.Create a constructor in a AsyncTask and send the button as parameter.  ex. getApi(buttonOne).execute();

2. Inside a getApi() constructor declare a local variable "Button" and assigned to that.
3. In onPostExecute() -> buttonOne.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE).

In asyncTask , "onPostExecute()" will perform in a main thread. UI elements should only get update in a main thread. So that passing a UI element into an Asynctask and it can be update inside the onPostExecute.

Comment: can you give me example

Comment: CallAsync(myButton).execute();        class    CallAsync extends AsyncTask<>  {   Button button;      CallAsync(button){ this.button = button;    }    doInBackgrounds(){....}   onPostExecute(){  button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) }  }